# Get total amount of files in entire Google Drive using GAPI

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Is there a way to just get the number of files in the entire drive before going through the entire list using the list api? I can't seem to find the data I need, I can get the total storage quota, but I just need the number of files in the drive so I can show progress in my UI.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a total for the number of files on a Google drive account is going to be doing a File.list and looping though everything.  Depending upon how many files you have you may have to do some pagination.

The only other option would be to use About which will return the amount of storage used but not the total of files, which doesnt sound like what you are after.